# update counter in newcommand without printing the result of the command

Tags: counters, xstring

In the following MWE I want to update my counter via a custom command `\noofwords`, but it

- writes an error on line 25: `Missing number, treated as zero. \noofwords`
- writes the PDF otherwise just fine
- the new value of the counter (at least I thought it would be its value) gets printed in the document when I call the command `\noofwords` (which is 2 and therefore 1 less than expected, as it should be 3)
- writes the initial value of `\thenoofwords` (which is 1) instead of the updated value (which should be 3 as mentioned before)

Why is that and what would be a way to solve or circumvent this problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\test}{word1, word2, word3}

\newcounter{noofcommas}
\setcounter{noofcommas}{1}

\newcounter{noofwords}
\setcounter{noofcommas}{1}

\newcommand{\noofwords}{ %
    \setcounter{noofwords}{
    \setcounter{noofcommas}{ %
        \StrCount{\test}{,}}}
    \refstepcounter{noofwords}}

\begin{document}
    
\thenoofcommas

\noofwords

\thenoofwords

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\StrCount{\test}{,}` does not expand to a number, it is like going `\setcounter{noofcommas}{\newcommand\tmp{3}\tmp}` which would give the same sort of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands of xstring have an optional argument where you can add a command which stores the result. This can then be used in a `\setcounter`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\test}{word1, word2, word3}

\newcounter{noofcommas}
\setcounter{noofcommas}{1}

\newcounter{noofwords}
\setcounter{noofcommas}{1}


\begin{document}

\StrCount{\test}{,}[\numofcommas]
\setcounter{noofcommas}{\numofcommas}

\thenoofcommas

\end{document}
```

I removed the `inputenc` line as it is not longer needed in a current LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

When using `\setcounter{noofwords}{...}`, `...` must be a ⟨number⟩ according to TeX's grammar. In your case, the `...` argument is `⟨space token⟩\setcounter{noofcommas}{⟨space token⟩\StrCount{\test}{,}}`; containing an assignment (the `\setcounter` operation), it is definitely not a ⟨number⟩. Besides, while `\StrCount{\test}{,}` typesets an integer, it doesn't *expand* to a ⟨number⟩ (if it did, it would *be* a ⟨number⟩). Because of this, it can't be used in contexts where TeX expects a ⟨number⟩.

As Ulrike Fischer [wrote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611530/73317), you can use the optional argument of `\StrCount` to tell it to store the resulting count in a macro of your choice (`\tmp` here):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\test}{word1, word2, word3}

\newcounter{noofcommas}
\newcounter{noofwords}

\newcommand{\noofwords}{%
  \StrCount{\test}{,}[\tmp]%
  \setcounter{noofcommas}{\tmp}%
  \setcounter{noofwords}{\value{noofcommas}}%
  \stepcounter{noofwords}%
}

\begin{document}

\thenoofcommas\noofwords

\thenoofwords

\end{document}
```

[image]

Beware of the spaces you put before `%` (some of them produce what I noted as ⟨space token⟩ above). They could cause you problems (mostly spurious spaces).

The above solution works but I would do it differently. The commands `\numItems` and `\numItemsOneLevelExp` below both *expand* to a ⟨number⟩; thus, they can be directly used in all kinds of places where only expansion takes place (known as “expansion-only contexts”)—in particular in those where TeX expects a ⟨number⟩. They will also hopefully draw your attention on the difference between `\test` (a single control sequence token) and the first-level expansion of `\test` (the token list `word1, word2, word3` in the example [with standard category codes]).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if your LaTeX format is older than 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \numItems { m }
  {
    \clist_count:n {#1}
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_count:n { V }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \numItemsOneLevelExp { m }
  {
    \clist_count:V #1
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\numItems{word1, word2, blah blah 3, word4}

\newcommand*{\test}{word1, word2, word3}%
\numItemsOneLevelExp{\test}

% Use in an expansion-only context (inside \numexpr)
\edef\zzz{\the\numexpr \numItemsOneLevelExp{\test}*10}%
%\show\zzz          % \zzz=macro:->30.

\end{document}
```

[image]